# Cannot use lagom on IntelliJ for my Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, lagom

I started a new Maven project and try to get `lagom` to work on my Maven project. On my Run Configurations I have inputted `lagom:runAll` under Command Line. However, when I run my project I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.578 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-17T11:25:31+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'lagom' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/home/andrea/.m2/repository), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Does anyone understand why I am unable to spot lagom library? Thanks in advance for the help, cheers!

Comment: are you using "mvn lagom:runAll" ?

Comment: @YogendraR hey thanks for your answer. when should I use that? when I run the project? I run it from the `Run` button on intellij

Comment: go to your project's root directory and run the command

Comment: @YogendraR ok done!  it displays the same error

Comment: how did you created your project. using maven archetype ? try "mvn clean install" and re-run

Comment: @YogendraR still same error unfortunately :/

Comment: how did you created your project ? can you show your pom.xml

Comment: See e.g. https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/LagomBuild.html#Defining-a-build-in-Maven

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that Maven does not know anything about external plugins by default, and this extends to modules.  Unless told so in the pom.xml (which implicitly implies any parent poms) a module has no knowledge of what happens in other modules.

Either you need to invoke lagom with the full artifact name  or you need to configure lagom in your pom.xml (preferably using dependency management in the parent pom)